# Mongoose find returning odd object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

my current problem is with the db.collection.find() mongoose command. I'm relatively new to mongoose/mongodb, but I've gotten the hang of the concepts of it. Here is the test code I've been trying to run:

```
mongoose.connect(url);
function main() 
{
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('open', function() {

        db.collection('Tweet').find({id: 631460910368956400}, function (err, data){
            console.log(data);
        })


        /*var coll = db.collection('Tweet');
         db.collection('Tweet').findOne({id: 631460910368956400},function (err, ret) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log(ret['id']);

         //db.close();
        });*/
    });
} 
main();
```

The data returned from the non commented out field is a strange object:

```
{ connection: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler:
   { s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: {},
  ns: 'TEST.Tweet',
  cmd: { find: 'TEST.Tweet', limit: 0, skip: 0, query: {}, slaveOk: false },
  options:
   { skip: 0,
     limit: 0,
     raw: undefined,
     hint: null,
     timeout: undefined,
     slaveOk: false,
     db:
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        s: [Object],
        serverConfig: [Getter],
         bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
         databaseName: [Getter],
```

etc etc... it goes on for much longer.

The IP address is a remote connection that successfully connects. I can do things like add and remove documents, but cannot actually view the documents from the javascript. I know that it is caused due to some kind of asynchronous problem, however I'm not sure how to fix it. Also, the commented out code for .findOne() seems to pull data completely fine in the code above.

What would be the problem with the code for the .find() function? An explanation for why the current error in data retrieving would be great also.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is because you have returned the database object from the native driver. It returns a "cursor", which is the "odd object" you speak of. You probably want the mongoose model methods instead.

Comment: This is incredibly poor documention on the part of Mongoose and native-mongodb-driver. Wasting 3 hours doing the wrong things because they have bad information in multiple places.

Answer (score 4):

The object you receive is a [`Cursor`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) which is an object used to retrieve the actual results.

When you are sure your query will never return more than one object (like in this case where you query by the always unique `_id` field), you can use `db.collection('Tweet').findOne(` which will return just that object without the additional layer of indirection.

But when your query can potentially return more than one document, you need to use a cursor. To resolve the cursor, you can turn it into an array of documents by using `cursor.toArray`:

```
    db.collection('Tweet').find({}, function (err, cursor){
        cursor.toArray().forEach(function(doc) { 
            console.log(doc);
        });
    })
```

This is the most simple version. For more information about cursors, refer to the documentation linked above.

By the way: So far you only used the functionality of the native driver. When you want to use Mongoose to query objects, you might want to use the methods of the Mongoose model object.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I did not know that Cursors would not return multiple objects. I've tried running the to.Array() for the return from the function, however it always returns with a "MongoError: Callback is mandatory" error. When I add a callback in* it never seems to go inside. Is this a problem with my collection? or would it be a problem with the code

Comment: I found out that the error was that the storage for the array was too large so it was crashing my code or something. After limiting it to a X query limit, it works. Thanks!! This test currently is using the native driver due to the fact that the schema's are dynamic. I have yet to figure out / research a way to query dynamic schema querying. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @erics to process large datasets, you can use `cursor.batchSize` and then `cursor.each` in its callback. This will load the documents in smaller batches.